# Whenever I try to run a sql script, I get stuck

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.5

When I try to restore Mysql databases, during the part where you run the script, workbench gets stuck and won't proceed

```
Mysql version 5.5
workbench version 6.3 CE
sql file size 4360 mb
```

[image: Workbench stuck]

Whenever this happens I restart the sql service but to no avail, also tried to remove any special characters in the sql script via notepad++

Comment: mydql 5,5 is long obsolite. see if xour code work with 5,7 or 8.3

Comment: and what are msql bases?

Comment: "Msql bases" hopefully not meaning Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL), and triple-hopefully not meaning [mSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSQL).

Comment: It ws just a typo, it is realy Mysql